# Disassembling IA32 32 bit AT&T assembly code of a function in C

Tags: c, 32-bit, disassembly

[Edited]
Could someone explain to me how we get the values of M and N in this problem, going through each line of the corresponding assembly code?

I always get stumped at the movl array2 part.

M and N are constants defined using #define

```
#define M <some value>
#define N <some value>

int array1[M][N]; 
int array2[N][M];
int copy(int i, int j)
{
array1[i][j] = array2[j][i];
}
```

If the above code generates the following assembly code: How do we deduce the values of the constants M and N?

```
  copy:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp 
    pushl %ebx
    movl 8(%ebp), %ecx 
    movl 12(%ebp), %ebx
    leal (%ecx, %ecx, 8), %edx
    sall $2, %edx 
    movl %ebx, %eax 
    sall $4, %eax 
    subl %ebx, %eax 
    sall $2, %eax
    movl array2(%eax, %ecx, 4), %eax
    movl %eax, array1(%edx, %ebx, 4)
    popl %ebx
    movl %ebp,%esp 
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

Comment: Do you really expect us to type all that? Don't post images of code! Please fix your question.

Comment: why the code as image???

Comment: What do you mean when you say "we get the values of M and N"? Did you mean `i` and `j`?

Comment: `#define M;` => that's not going to compile

Comment: The #define directive cannot be included in the compilation process I think because we inherently don't know their values and the assembly code probably has a hint to their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys, after much research I was able to find a solution. Correct me if I am wrong.

So going through the following assembly step by step: (Added line numbers for ease)

M and N are constants defined using #define

```
int array1[M][N]; 
int array2[N][M];
int copy(int i, int j)
{
array1[i][j] = array2[j][i];
}

copy:
   1  pushl %ebp 
   2  movl %esp, %ebp 
   3  pushl %ebx
   4  movl 8(%ebp), %ecx 
   5  movl 12(%ebp), %ebx
   6  leal (%ecx, %ecx, 8), %edx
   7  sall $2, %edx 
   8  movl %ebx, %eax 
   9  sall $4, %eax 
  10  subl %ebx, %eax 
  11  sall $2, %eax
  12  movl array2(%eax, %ecx, 4), %eax
  13  movl %eax, array1(%edx, %ebx, 4)
  14  popl %ebx
  15  movl %ebp,%esp 
  16  popl %ebp
      ret
```

1. Push `%ebp` into stack
2. `%ebp` points to `%esp`
3. Push `%ebx` into stack
4. `%ecx` equals `int i` (index for array access)
5. `%ebx` equals `int j` (index for array access)
6. `%edx` equals `8 * %ecx + %ecx` or `9i`
7. `%edx` equals `36i` after a left binary shift of `2`
8. `%eax` equals %ebx or `j`
9. `%eax` equals `16j` after a left binary shift of `4`
10. `%eax` equals `%eax - %ebx = 16j - j = 15j`
11. `%eax` equals `60j` after a left binary shift of `2`
12. `%eax` equals array2 element with index `[4%ecx + %ebx] or [4i + 60j]`
13. Element with index `[ 4%ebx + %edx ] or [ 4j + 36i ]` of array1 equals `%eax` or `[4i + 60j]`

> A swap of the two array elements done in 12 and 13 using %eax as
>   intermediary register.

14. `%ebx` popped
15. `%esp`'s old value restored
16. `%ebp` popped

Now we assume `array1[i][j]`'s element access to be equal to `4Ni + 4j`

And `array2[j][i]`'s element access to be equal to `4Mj + 4i`.

( The 4 in each index term as int is of 4 bytes and i, j are individual offsets from starting array location )
This is true because C stores arrays in a row major form.

So equating we get, M = 15 and N = 9.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check other parts of the assembly. For example, if you define M and N as 8 both, you will find the following in the assembly

```
array1:
    .zero   256
array2:
    .zero   256
```

because on my machine, int is 4 bytes and 8 times 8 is 64. And 64 * 4 = 256. The sample assembly can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/g/AAVfk8) .

Comment: I think there's a way to find the answer without having to assume the values of M and N, but I do not think we need to know the other parts of the assembly.